# What the UrlParameter.Optional really is?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

At first, I thought it is defined as some kind of an **enum**. But it is not.

The UrlParameter is defined as below:

```
// Summary:
//     Represents an optional parameter that is used by the System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler
//     class during routing.
public sealed class UrlParameter
{
    // Summary:
    //     Contains the read-only value for the optional parameter.
    public static readonly UrlParameter Optional;

    // Summary:
    //     Returns an empty string. This method supports the ASP.NET MVC infrastructure
    //     and is not intended to be used directly from your code.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An empty string.
    public override string ToString();
}
```

And ILSpy shows the implementation as:

```
// System.Web.Mvc.UrlParameter
/// <summary>Contains the read-only value for the optional parameter.</summary>
public static readonly UrlParameter Optional = new UrlParameter();
```

So how does MVC know not to put the optional parameter into the dictionary when it sees the following code? **After all, the code below just assign a new instance of UrlParameter to the id.**

```
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the broader context.

The complete source code for `UrlParameter` is

```
public sealed class UrlParameter {

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Security", "CA2104:DoNotDeclareReadOnlyMutableReferenceTypes", Justification = "This type is immutable.")]
    public static readonly UrlParameter Optional = new UrlParameter();

    // singleton constructor
    private UrlParameter() { }

    public override string ToString() {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

`UrlParameter.Optional` is the only possible instance of `UrlParameter`.
In other words, the entire `UrlParameter` class exists only as a placeholder for optional parameters.

Comment: +1, Ummm, I'm curious to know why they implemented `ToString` that bizarre way.

Comment: @gdoron: What do you mean? They just want it to show as blank when inspecting defaults objects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If the entire UrlParameter class exists only as a place holder for optional parameters, why not name it like OptionalUrlParameter at the very beginning?

Comment: @smwikipedia: To make your code more readable.  Writing `OptionalUrlParameter.Optional` or `OptionalUrlParameter.Instance` would look weird.

Comment: As far as MVC itself is concerned, that would be the correct name for this type.